# how to use traverse in three.js to modify wireframe

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have several objects, when it was selected the check box would change the wireframe property to true or false ( run time) .

```
function toggleWireFrame(obj){
     var f = function(obj2)
     {
         if(obj2.hasOwnProperty("material")){
     obj2.material.wireframe=!obj2.material.wireframe;
     }          
  }
     obj.traverse(f);   
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Your code should work, if you call `toggleWireFrame` on each of the meshes, one by one.

```
toggleWireFrame(meshA);
toggleWireFrame(meshB);
```

This would make sense if each of these meshes are made up of several meshes and you need to toggle all the sub-meshes too. You might get mesh hierarchies like that a lot if you import models from an OBJ file, for example.

2) Or did you want to call `toggleWireFrame` only once and have all your meshes' wireframe toggled?

If that's the case, you will have to call

`toggleWireFrame(scene);`

or even

`toggleWireFrame(myObject3D);`

where `myObject3D` is an `Object3D` instance which is the parent of all the meshes that you want to toggle wireframe status.

`traverse()` works by iterating through all children and grandchildren of the starting object. You need to make sure that all the objects that you want to toggle to wireframe is parented under this starting object, as shown in the examples above.

3) Another option is to use an array to store each material as they are created, and then iterate through this array to change the wireframe attribute when the user toggles the check box.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use on my projects, it just inverses the boolean since it will be true or false.

```
function wireframeToggle(i) {
    bool = i.material.wireframe;
    i.material.wireframe = !bool;
}
```

[Working example](http://www.matthewriches.com/labs/systemgen/) (x for wireframe)

Comment: I have several objects and I would like to change all. So I used the traverse but it does not work. With your code I can not change anything = (

Comment: In the attached example I have all the elements in an array, so just loop through it, I guess you could do the same thing with a three group too...